# Getting an exception with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm unit testing a method which uses automapper to map a class from my domain to a linq to sql class.  Roughly, the classes and mapping are below (The SupplierEligibilityAllocated is a L2S auto generated class).

```
public class SupplierEligibilityTransactionByQuantity
{
    public decimal Eligibility { get; private set; }
    public decimal CoreValue { get; private set; }
    public int? TransactionId { get; private set; }
    public SupplierTransactionStatus Status { get; private set; }
    public int? DebitId { get; set; }
    public int ManifestId { get; private set; }
}

public partial class SupplierEligibilityAllocated
{
 private int _SupplierEligibilityCreditId;
 private int _ManifestId;
 private System.Nullable<int> _QuantityApplied;
 private System.Nullable<decimal> _AmountApplied;
 private System.Nullable<decimal> _CoresReservedByAmount;
 private System.DateTime _InsertDate;
 private EntityRef<Manifest> _Manifest;
 private EntityRef<SupplierEligibilityCredit> _SupplierEligibilityCredit;
}

private static void Map_SupplierEligibilityTransactionByQuantity_To_SupplierEligibilityAllocated()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<EligibilityTransactionByQuantity, SupplierEligibilityAllocated>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SupplierEligibilityCreditId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TransactionId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ManifestId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ManifestId))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.QuantityApplied, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToInt32(src.Eligibility)))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.AmountApplied, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CoresReservedByAmount, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.InsertDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.UtcNow))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Manifest, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SupplierEligibilityCredit, opt => opt.Ignore());
}
```

When the method executes the mapping, though, it throws the following exception.

```
Trying to map SupplierEligibilityTransactionByQuantity to SupplierEligibilityAllocated.
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.AutoMapper.IMappingEngineRunner.Map(ResolutionContext context)
at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map(Object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
at AutoMapper.MappingEngine.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map[TSource,TDestination](TSource source)
```

I verified that I am creating the mapping before the test and I called `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` without any problems.  I also manually did the mapping without any problems.  Anybody have an idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: for any1 there is always the possibility u put the IgnoreDataMember attr, and that means that outside ur class u cant see it, that was my problem with this ex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears you are specifying the wrong type on your call to `Mapper.CreateMap`

Try doing something like the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SupplierEligibilityTransactionByQuantity, SupplierEligibilityAllocated>()
```

Comment: Doh, I overlooked the obvious.  I was mapping the wrong type, which explains the exception and why the AssertConfigurationIsValid() wasn't having a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If any one using `Mapper.Map()` check your mapping class & table/store procedure properly.

```
public static CustomerLedgerViewModel ToModel(this DJBL_tblCustomerCurrentLedger obj)
{
    return Mapper.Map<DJBL_tblCustomerCurrentLedger, CustomerLedgerViewModel>(obj);
}

public static DJBL_tblCustomerCurrentLedger ToEntity(this CustomerLedgerViewModel model)
{
    return Mapper.Map<CustomerLedgerViewModel, DJBL_tblCustomerCurrentLedger>(model);
}
```