# Linq update with using automapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, automapper, updates

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _EditCustomer(CustomerViewModel CustomerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            Customers customer = entity.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.sno == CustomerViewModel.sno);
            customer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel, Customers>(CustomerViewModel);
            entity.SaveChanges();

            return Content("<div class=\"success\">Müşteri düzenleme işlemi başarılı.</div>", "text/html");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Müşteri güncelleme hatası.");
        }
    }

    //Updating customer is failed!
    CustomerViewModel.Cities = entity.Cities;
    CustomerViewModel.PowerSuppliers = entity.PowerSuppliers;
    CustomerViewModel.Sectors = entity.Sectors;

    return PartialView(CustomerViewModel);
}
```

I debugged the code, and then in runtime customer is updating(automapper is working, I can see the changes), but `entity.SaveChanges();` is not working.

Is there any another way to update records, when using automapper?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates new customer entity, which is not attached to context:

```
var newCustomer = Mapper.Map<CustomerViewModel, Customers>(CustomerViewModel);
```

To update existing entity, use following `Map` method of automapper:

```
Mapper.Map(CustomerViewModel, customer);
```

Comment: `Customers customer = entity.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.sno == CustomerViewModel.sno);
                    customer = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(CustomerViewModel, customer);
                    entity.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I sorry, I think problem is customerId=0 I use hiddenFor but it returns 0

Comment: Error: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

Comment: You should create mapping: `Mapper.Create<CustomerViewModel, Customers>();` Also I'd use different name for `CustomerViewModel` parameter, at least one which is camel-case `customerViewModel`.

Comment: In my App_Start, I have this: `Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, Customers>();` and this: `Mapper.CreateMap<Customers, CustomerViewModel>();`.

Comment: When I try to create new Customer with mapper it work. But I try to use your suggestion map method, I get this error.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi this method works, when appropriate mapping exist. Set a breakpoint and verify your `customer` when you getting it from context. Maybe it has `null` value.

Comment: It is not null. I use auto mapper to save my time, but it is the exact opposite :) I cant do your suggestion.Also, Thanks for helps.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I did that trick many times and it works. According to your exception, something wrong with you mapping. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942691/getting-an-exception-with-automapper